Isotope Combination filters Dropdown
I've got an issue with isotope metafizzy filters combination : https://isotope.metafizzy.co/
I'm building a line-up for concerts and meetings.
And for example i have a band that plays in London on Wednesday and in Washington on friday.
When I select Town : London / Date : Friday
It also shows me the band in concert in Washington on Friday
Here is my javascript code :

$(window).load(function(){  
    
// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.grid-item').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
});

// store filter for each group
var filters = {};

$('.filters').on( 'change', function( event ) {
  var $select = $( event.target );
  // get group key
  var filterGroup = $select.attr('value-group');
  // set filter for group
  filters[ filterGroup ] = event.target.value;
  // combine filters
  var filterValue = concatValues( filters );
  // set filter for Isotope
  $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});

// flatten object by concatting values
function concatValues( obj ) {
  var value = '';
  for ( var prop in obj ) {
    value += obj[ prop ];
  }
  return value;
}
})  


Maybe with this fiddle it's more clear : https://jsfiddle.net/9st56qhd/1/
Thanks for your help

It only shows London's event for me if I select concert, London and Friday 7

@LajosArpad yes but my problem is that the concert is in Washington on Friday 7

I see. The issue appears to be that Isotope searches for words, but not for sentences. London and friday are both in the text, so it yields a "found" result. Somehow you would need to filter by sentence, but I'm unsure how you are to achieve that using Isotope
